# Web API загрузка файла в папку

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp-net-core-mvc

Доброго времени суток!
    Что есть: контроллер API с методом, который принимает файл, который загружаю через Postman в form-data прикрепляю файл.
    Проблема: в контроллер проваливается, но файла нет. Пробовал писать в параметрах метода IFormFile, но в этом случае в метод вообще не попадает а возвращается пустота.
    Мой код:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Impulse_Back_end.Models;
using Impulse_Back_end.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Impulse_Back_end.Core.Interfaces;

namespace Impulse_Back_end.Controllers {
    [ApiController, Route("api/data/upload")]
    public class FileUploadController : Controller {
        ApplicationDbContext db;
        public FileUploadController(ApplicationDbContext _context) {
            db = _context;
        }

        [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit, Route("file")]
        public IActionResult Upload() {
            try {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var folderName = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "images");
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

                if (file.Length > 0) {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                    var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create)) {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }

                    return Ok(new { dbPath });
                }
                else {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как отправляю через Postman
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример простейшего метода загрузки без проверок и прочего

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit, Route("file")]
public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
{
    using(var fstream = new FileInfo(file.FileName).Create())
    {
        file.CopyTo(fstream);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

А теперь следим за руками в Postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя параметра типа IFormFile (в примере - `file`) и значение поля KEY у записи с загружаемым фалом (обведено на картинке) **обязаны совпадать**, если эти значения отличаются, вы получите null в контроллере вместо потока загружаемого файла.

От себя добавлю, что для ручного тестирования я предпочитаю использовать Swagger, он несколько удобнее, т.к. генерирует корректные запросы самостоятельно, на основе параметров ваших контроллеров.